# Any difference? "I am happy being single" and "I am happy that I am single"

Tags: sentence-combination

Today, it is St valentine's day and I heard a lady on TV saying "I am happy being single".

I thought about what we are taught at school for creating this meaning. We were taught to give this meaning by means of a sentence like this: "I am happy that I am single.". Because, there are two separate sentences in this long sentence: 1) I am happy. 2) I am single, so it feels we should use "that" to combine those two separate sentences, shouldn't we?.

However, the lady's sentence seems to be shorter and more practical. I thought I could use it if her way of combining two separate sentences this way is completely the same and correct.

So, I wonder is there any difference between the following sentences:

- I am happy that I am single.
- I am happy being single.

And if they are all the same in meaning, can we combine any two such separate  sentences without having to use "that"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight difference, though it might not matter.

*I am happy that X* means that I am satisfied with X, or approving of X. It doesn't say whether I am generally happy in my life. So *I am sorry you were in a car crash, but happy that you were uninjured* makes sense. *I am happy about X* has a similar meaning.

On the other hand, *I am happy being X*, while it could have the same sort of restricted meaning, more naturally means something like *I am generally happy in my life, because (or even though) I am X*. (The tone of voice will generally tell you whether the relation is "because" or "even though").